How to describe a deployment node in more detail than the model describes in Structurizr/C4?
In my software model, part of the system is of course a database. I could view it as a separate softwareSystem or perhaps just a container. Let's say it's:
db = softwareSystem "Database"
softwareSystem "My App" {
   -> db "Reads/writes data"
}

This is sufficient as far as my logical relationships are concerned. In my deployment diagram though, I want to highlight that I'm using a connection-pooling proxy, a hot-standby and an offsite backup. Is it possible to encompass all that in a deploymentEnvironment?
Doing something like this just renders the database as one blob without more details:
deploymentNode "AWS RDS" {
    softwareSystemInstance db

    group "Multi-AZ" {
        deploymentNode "Postgres" {
            -> backup "Backup"
        }
        deploymentNode "Hot standby"
    }

    deploymentNode "Proxy"
}


Moving softwareSystemInstance db into deploymentNode "Postgres" includes that, but still omits the proxy and everything else.
I can't seem to find a notation that would make My App point to Proxy and Proxy point to Postgres and include all those details, without also including a proxy in the system model, where it doesn't seem to belong, because it's a detail of a specific deployment.

It's not clear if you're asking about how to use the Structurizr tool and/or its DSL (which would be off-topic here - we don't support tools) or about how to model the system. If you're asking about modeling, it could be helpful to also show the diagrams that result from using Structurizr. I think it's far more likely that we'd be able to look at how to effectively visualize your system if we can see how it's visualized now. I tried to drop your JSON into the Structurizr web app, either I'm not doing it right or it's not fully valid.

Thanks for the feedback. I've included a sample of the output I currently get. As you see, only the node explicitly containing an instance of something is rendered, all the other nodes I defined aren't. How would I express an abstract "database" as a component, but include more details about that component in the deployment diagram only? I'm probably thinking about this the wrong way in terms of C4, so would be happy about an answer at that level.

It would be helpful if you posted the diagrams that are the actual output from the DSL. Or perhaps all of your DSL. I don't see AWS, ap-northeast-1, Lambda on your DSL, for example. But I'm almost wondering if this is a Structurizr issue. C4 allows you to express what you want, but I've only used it as a language in a graphical tool (primarily draw.io / diagrams.net).

Yes, I've minimised the example here, as the actual diagram is of course a lot bigger. If it's specific to Structurizr and that's off-topic here, then I suppose it can't be answered, with or without full example.
